# unable to access View (Image view and Textview)

Tags: android

This is my `Pageradapter` :

```
private class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            Context context;

            public MyAdapter(Context context) {
                super();
                this.context = context;
            }

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                ModelObject modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position];
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), container, false);
                TextView bottomTitle = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_title);
                ImageView topImageView =(ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.top_image_view);
                TextView topTitleTextview=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.top_title_text_view);
                TextView bottomDescriptionTextView=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.bottom_description_textview);
                bottomTitle.setText(pointsHelpItemDetailViewModel.getHelpItem().subtitle);
                int resId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(pointsHelpItemDetailViewModel.getHelpItem().image, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
                topImageView.setBackgroundResource(resId);
                topTitleTextview.setText(pointsHelpItemDetailViewModel.getHelpItem().subtitle);
                bottomDescriptionTextView.setText(pointsHelpItemDetailViewModel.getHelpItem().content);
                container.addView(layout);
                return layout;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
                collection.removeView((View) view);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return ModelObject.values().length;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                ModelObject customPagerEnum = ModelObject.values()[position];
                return context.getString(customPagerEnum.getTitleResId());
            }
        }
```

this is my ModelObject

```
public enum ModelObject {

    RED(R.color.tesco_red, R.layout.point_help_image_view),
    BLUE(R.color.tesco_blue, R.layout.point_help_decription_view);

    private int mTitleResId;
    private int mLayoutResId;

    ModelObject(int titleResId, int layoutResId) {
        mTitleResId = titleResId;
        mLayoutResId = layoutResId;
    }

    public int getTitleResId() {
        return mTitleResId;
    }

    public int getLayoutResId() {
        return mLayoutResId;
    }
}
```

i have added two layout point_`help_image_view`,`point_help_decription_view` in  first layout I have one `ImageView` and one `TextView` and in second layout two text view i want to access.

I am trying to access using given code but when i try to setText i am getting exception  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(int)'` on a null object reference . please help me how to access view in pager adapter .

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522489/nullpointerexception-on-using-setbackgroundresource

Comment: but how this inside         public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {  when i use ur solution its showing null in textview initialisation

Comment: Why show null?? you can see and hope you fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: i need to access two  two layout view  so that i can  display it some text or image please check my question

Comment: @ Masum any  suggestion for this issue because not able to resolve this issue

Comment: I think at first you implement this. Then try a new one. May help this. https://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial

Comment: yes i have use same @Masum can you please suggest me in this example how to print blue and red  layout textview programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        ModelObject modelObject = ModelObject.values()[position];
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(modelObject.getLayoutResId(), container, false);

        TextView bottomTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_title);
        bottomTitle.setText("MARSH");

        return itemView;
    }
```

Comment: thanx wait let me check this

Comment: can u please tell me which card_pager_adv which layout is this is it when Viewpager  is there ? @Vishrut Mavani

Comment: replace card_pager_adv with your layout name.

Comment: but we have two different layout  please check in ModelObject which one we have to put ?

Comment: but still same error  i dont know how to access textview @Vishrut Mavani  i have used this example https://www.journaldev.com/10096/android-viewpager-example-tutorial

Comment: put your layout files in question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189289/discussion-between-marsh-and-vishrut-mavani).

Comment: @VishrutMavani he's getting error at `setBackgroundResource()` not `setText()`

Comment: any  suggestion for this issue because not able to resolve this issue @VishrutMavani